# Multiple thread groups affecting each other

Tags: jmeter

I have created a test plan with multiple thread groups that I want to execute simultaneously.

One group (A) involves tagging a folder with 1000 images in it, so it takes approx 10 seconds to respond.
The other group (B) is real quick.

What I've found is that group B seems to "stick" and wait for thread A to complete.  Now all the reading I've done says that thread groups should be totally independant, but this doesn't seem to be the case in my test plan.

I have an HTTP defaults manager, cookie manager and user defined variables that are shared between groups (but have tried adding them in the separate thread groups).

Anyone got any idea why this should be?

Script is here:  https://www.dropbox.com/sh/fhdof4ynjt73s2p/mkrphWcfHK
(likely will not run or stick though as this uses internal URL's)

Comment: Any feedback on this ? was my answer helpful ?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is not in JMeter, it is the application that is locking.

Looking at your test, you seem to use one user to do your load test, this clearly explains your issue and makes your test unrealistic as you have around 20 Users logged with the same user/password.